# 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: node.js, angular-cli-v7

I was installed new version of nodejs. I could updated the angular/cli globally on my machine. But still getting ng is not recognized as the name of  the cmdlet. Is there any way to check the ng version in both visual studio code and command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

## At first You Can Install Node Then Install Angular:

- To download [click here](https://nodejs.org/en/) or visit https://nodejs.org/en/
- Then open cmd and try the command given bellow

  - `npm install -g @angular/cli`

### If npm not found or not recognized then you can follow the following steps:

- Search *environment variables* from start menu's search box.
- Click it then go to *Environment Variables*
- Click **PATH**
- click **Edit**
- Click **New** and try to *copy* and *paste* your path for '*bin*' folder [find where you installed the node] for example according to my machine '`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`'

#### If you got any error. try the another step:

- Click **New**, then browse for the '*bin*' folder

> If you got any error still now, please take a screen shot and post with description as needed.